# How to use dgels in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, matrix, lapack, lapacke

I am trying to solve Ax = b in Xcode with a rectangular A matrix where the size of A and b depend on the size of different arrays that I have stored. I have tried using dgels, but for some reason I get this error

```
** on entry to DGELS , parameter number 8 had an illegal value dgesv_ fails -8
```

This corresponds to the work double matrix input and I can't figure out why.

int numberOfPlays = (int)[playArray count];
    int numberOfSignals = (int)[signalMappings count];

```
// now create A Matrix and b vector
double playElements[numberOfPlays][numberOfSignals];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlays; i = i + 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSignals; j = j + 1) {
        playElements[i][j] = 0.0;
    }
}
double outputElements[numberOfPlays][1];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlays; i = i + 1) {
    outputElements[i][0] = 0.0;
}

...update the elements of the matrices

// now solve the matrix
__CLPK_integer m = numberOfPlays;
__CLPK_integer n = numberOfSignals;
__CLPK_integer nrhs = 1;
__CLPK_integer info;
__CLPK_integer lda = n;
__CLPK_integer ldb = 1;
int min = n;
if (m < n) {
    min = m;
}
__CLPK_integer workSize = min * 2;
double *work = (double *)malloc(workSize*sizeof(double));
dgels_("N", &m, &n, &nrhs, *playElements, &lda, *outputElements, &ldb, work, &workSize, &info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter number 8 corresponds to `ldb`, which should be `>= max(1, m, n)`. So in your case, this should be `m` or `n` (whichever is bigger).

I was bitten by this as well and some of the documentation is rather unclear on this. I traced the error to [Lapack C](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/CLAPACK-3.1.1/SRC/dgels.c) source which makes it clear.